# Failed to retrive Bitmap from SoftReference in Android

Tags: android

I put my bitmap into hashmap as:

```
HashMap<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>> imageMap = new HashMap<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>>();

....

bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputstream);

imageMap.put(String.valueOf(i), new SoftReference<Bitmap>(bitmap));
```

And I increment it every time and I am getting the bitmap also.

I retrive bitmap by:

```
SoftReference<Bitmap> setValue = imageMap.get(String.valueOf(count));

Bitmap bitmap=setValue.get();
```

I increment count every time .But I get bitmap for a particular count only.How can we get every bitmap from hashmap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SoftReference doesn't garantee object to stay in memory, so if You receive null for bitmap, You should decode it again and put into HashMap.

Comment: Decoding takes a lot of time. That's why I decode all images at the bugining itself. What can I do to avoid this time delay?

Comment: it actually depends on the way You're using images. Have You checked http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html ? This way might be more applicable, because SoftReference might be cleared too fast.